# Consign a PHP file on Xampp Documentroot

Tags: php

I think this is a very stupid question but I hope that you guys can help me.
In Xampp you got a documentroot folder where I can consign my path.

Now I realised that everytime I put on my path an "index.html" file, localhost will execute that.
Can I consign an ".php" file, so that localhost can execute that file normally like html?
Or what should I do?
Because in my php there is HTML too.

Kind regards
neverbesuccessfull

Comment: `index.php` is also run if it exists in the DocumentRoot folder

Comment: Oh my godness thank you very much!